# Gutters in Susy remaining intact as spacing between elements. Bonus: wider doesn't work

Tags: susy-compass, susy-sass, susy, susy-next

There's an unwanted space between two blocks in susy. It seems to follow the size of the grid exactly, despite using the `wide` feature.

```
$susy: (
  columns: 9,
  gutters: 0.454,
  debug:(image: show,
  output : overlay,)
)
;
#grid{
    @include container(9);
    @include background-grid; 
    gutter-width: 0.454;
    }

#main_side_img{
  @include span(1.75 wide of 9);
}  

#main_heading_container{
  @include span(4 of 9);
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/7Yxm5Sa.jpg);
  }
```

The code above, with `#main_side_img` set to `1.75` creates this:
[image]

So I set the value of `#main_side_img` to `2` and much to my dismay the space between the two boxes remained constant, and the gutter simply moved over!

[image]

The gutter remains constant independent of the value I set for the span argument.

Bonus: isn't wider supposed to fill in the gutter on the left and on the right? It is filling in 2 gutter's-widths to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `no-gutters` keyword to your wide span. While `wide` tells it to add more space to the span width, it does not automatically remove the gutter output.

`@include span(1.75 wide of 9 no-gutters);`